# I want to download the excel file which is in the specific path in the project directory on button click or as a link tag

Tags: javascript

I want to download an excel file on click of the button. no ajax call/ server request. The excel file is placed in the directory of the project folder.

I have tried to download using HTML anchor tag

```
<p><a href="/ExcelFile.xlsx" download> Click to Download </a></p>
```

also tried placing the xlsx file in the folder still didn't work

```
<p><a href="TestFile/ExcelFile.xlsx" download> Click to Download </a></p>

<p><a href="/TestFile/ExcelFile.xlsx" download> Click to Download </a></p>
```

I am getting an error, no file content in the downloads pane.

Comment: Are you using a supported browser ? https://caniuse.com/#feat=download